# Genaric type parsing in Scala with default value

Tags: scala

I am looking for a Generic functional way to convert between Scala String to any numeric type. I need in case of failure to pass a default value.

For example, I need to convert from `String` to `Int` but in case the String to Int conversion failed. I need to pass a default value without having `throws java.lang.NumberFormatException`. I tried [this](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-parse-number-int-long-float-bigint-from-string-in-scala) way but doesn't get my idea as I need it **generic** and also with **default** value in case of exception

Comment: Do you want to specify the default by yourself, or do you always want a common default like zero or one?

Comment: I need to add it by myself

Comment: Given that I would go with Dima's answer, or something similar. A typeclass is always a good solution for this kind of problems.

Comment: Actual, I was looking for a function to similar `.toInt` or `.toDouble`. But why typeclass is better solution? The solution related to `safeParse` do it correctly without any drawback.

Comment: The typeclass under the hood is the same, the idea of the typeclass is that given that the transformation from **String** to **Int** is always the same, why would I need to specify it every time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**: I updated the solution to parse from any type to any type. This makes the solution more generic based on the question requested. I think you can use Scala functional way to have the generic type `[T]` but you need to split it into two parts.

First to implement parse types which parses from any type `[U]` to 
any type `[T]`. `parseTypes` takes a function `canBuildFrom` as a parameter using Scala functional way. Then based on the output of this function you will checks if it parsed correctly or it has an exception. Also, in case it failed to parse you can pass a default parameter.

```
  def parseTypes[T,U](str: U, canBuildFrom: U ⇒ T): Either[java.lang.NumberFormatException, T] =
    Try(canBuildFrom(str)).map(Right(_)).getOrElse {
      Left(new java.lang.NumberFormatException(str.toString))
    }

  def safeParse[T,U](attributeValue: U, canBuildFrom: U ⇒ T, defaultValue: T): T = {
    parseTypes(attributeValue, canBuildFrom) match {
      case Right(x) ⇒ x
      case Left(x)  ⇒ defaultValue
      case _        ⇒ defaultValue
    }
  }


  def safeParseDoubleToBigDecimal(attributeValue: Double): BigDecimal = safeParse[BigDecimal,Double](attributeValue, toBigDecimal, 0.0)
```

You can use it to parse String to Int, Double, and Decimal as following:

```
  def safeParseStringToInt(attributeValue: String): Int = safeParse[Int,String](attributeValue, _.toInt, 0)

  def safeParseStringToDouble(attributeValue: String): Double = safeParse[Double ,String](attributeValue, _.toDouble, 0.0)

  def safeParseStringToBigDecimal(attributeValue: String): BigDecimal = safeParse[BigDecimal ,String](attributeValue, BigDecimal(_), 0.0)
  // example of usage
  val x:Int = safeParseStringToInt("123",0)
  val y:Int = safeParseStringToInt("aaa",0)
```

Update: I update this answer as I realized that @Dima's answer is somehow more functional and better than my answer I added the answer below copied from @Dima's answer as my answer marked as the correct answer.

```
 trait ParseIt[T] {
     protected def parse(s: String): T
     def apply(s: String) = Try(parse(s)).toOption
 }

 implicit object ParseInt extends ParseIt[Int] {
   protected def parse(s: String) = s.toInt
 }

 implicit object ParseDouble extends ParseIt[Double] {
   protected def parse(s: String) = s.toDouble
 }
 // etc ...

 def parse[T : ParseIt](s: String, orElse: => T) = 
   implicitly[ParseIt[T]](s).getOrElse(orElse)

 val n: Int = parse("123", 0)
 val d: Double = parse("123", 0.0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solve my problem. But Is there a way to convert from any generic to any generic?

Comment: I think you can do the same and customize the function and the expected exception type.

Comment: I like this solution as it seems to be simple and fit in my case.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing is implemented really nice with typeclasses:

```
 trait ParseIt[T] {
     protected def parse(s: String): T
     def apply(s: String) = Try(parse(s)).toOption
 }

 implicit object ParseInt extends ParseIt[Int] {
   protected def parse(s: String) = s.toInt
 }

 implicit object ParseDouble extends ParseIt[Double] {
   protected def parse(s: String) = s.toDouble
 }
 // etc ...

 def parse[T : ParseIt](s: String, orElse: => T) = 
   implicitly[ParseIt[T]](s).getOrElse(orElse)

 val n: Int = parse("123", 0)
 val d: Double = parse("123", 0.0)
```

Comment: nice solution - I pasted it in Scalafiddle - I had to add `apply` that it worked: `implicitly[ParseIt[T]].apply(s).getOrElse(orElse)` - typo?

Comment: Nice solution! - But If I need to have specific value in case of some exception, How can I implement it?

Comment: @Sa2012 Given the implementation, any exception will be catched by the `Try` in `apply`. Thus becoming a `None`. Thus, being replaced by the default.

Comment: If you care about the specific exception, you can just not convert the Try to an Option, and pattern match on the Exception.

Comment: @Dima I know it is late, but I realised your answer is somehow better than my answer and more FN style way. I added the solution up to make sure all the people showed your answer as the one who asked this question marked mine as correct.